Change of variable to find PDF of Y = U(X) given PDF of X
I am referring to the section on change of variable in 'Mathematics for Machine Learning' book. Essentially, given a random variable X defined in the range $[a, b]$, the ask is to find the PDF of random variable $Y = U(X)$, where $U$ is an invertible function. I am sharing relevant screenshots from the book which walk through the derivation process using the change of variable technique. My question is with respect to the fourth step.

Problem description:



Expressing CDF of Y in terms of CDF of X



PDF of y as differentiation of CDF of X



Applying chain rule and fundamental rule of calculus


Question: In step 4, after applying the reverse chain rule (on eq 6.139 to obtain eq 6.141), shouldn't the new integral limits be now $\int_{U(a)}^{y}$, as the integral is defined in terms of $y$ now? I also couldn't follow the derivation of eq 6.142 just after that.
I try deriving eq 6.142 as follow, but I am not sure about the accuracy of the line of reasoning.
First way (without expanding CDF into integral)
$F_y(y) = F_x(U^{-1}(y))$, hence taking derivative with respect to y,
$f_y(y) = \frac{d \{F_x(U^{-1}(y))\}}{d_y}$. Applying chain rule, we get
$f_y(y) = \frac{d \{F_x(U^{-1}(y))\}}{d_{U^{-1}(y)}} * \frac{d\{U^{-1}(y)\}}{d_y}$, or
$f_y(y) = f_x(U^{-1}(y)) * \frac{d}{d_y}[U^{-1}(y)]$
Second way (expanding CDF intergral)
$F_y(y) = F_x(U^{-1}(y)) = \int_{a}^{U^{-1}(y)} f_x(x) dx$.
Taking derivative with respect to y,
$f_y(y) = \frac{d}{d_y} [\int_{a}^{U^{-1}(y)} f_x(x) dx]$,
after change of variable,
$f_y(y) = \frac{d}{d_y} [\int_{U(a)}^{y} f_x(U^{-1}(y)) U^{-1'}(y) dy]$,
the expression inside the bracket is antiderivative of $f_x(U^{-1}(y)) U^{-1'}(y)$, hence by fundamental theorem of calculus,
$f_y(y) = f_x(U^{-1}(y)) U^{-1'}(y))$ or
$f_y(y) = f_x(U^{-1}(y)) \frac{d}{d_y} [U^{-1}(y))]$
Is there a gap in my understanding? I am not a formal student, so there's a good chance I may be missing something obvious. I Would really appreciate your inputs, Thanks :)

6.141 is indeed problematic, for the boundary problem you mentioned, and for the very bad notation (using $y$ twice for different purposes). Also, one could just use Leibinz rule to get from 6.139 to 6.142, if one would like to skip some middle steps.

Thanks @ZackFisher for confirming. I just checked, there's an errata request for this issue.
